# rtkit: list threads it is "supervising"?

Tags: systemd, pulseaudio, real-time, journalctl, rtkit-daemon

`rtkit` obviously knows which threads it is "supervising", since it spams syslog with messages like

```
rtkit-daemon[1277]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
```

However, the nefarious little thing doesn't seem to provide a way to list those "supervised" process / threads. `rtkitctl` has options to kill or restart the daemon and to "reset" the threads (whatever that means). At least on Debians, I don't see any other utilities. Maybe there are hidden `DBus` interfaces, or maybe the distro doesn't package some utilities.

So, without going the `ps` way, is there a way to list those "supervised" threads, or is this just another opaque aspect of the whole `dbus`/`systemd` ecosystem?

Comment: Similar? https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=318754

Comment: That one seems to be about disabling the rtkit-related log spam, whereas I'd want to see what the heck it is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

RTKit provides a DBus interface to retrieve this information.  Here's a shell script that demonstrates:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get the list of processes managed by rtkit
processes=$(dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1 --print-reply /org/freedesktop/RealtimeKit1 org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.GetManagedProcesses | awk '/array/ {flag=1; next} flag')

# Loop through each process and extract the process ID and thread count
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ uint32\ ([0-9]+) ]]; then
        pid="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    elif [[ $line =~ uint32\ ([0-9]+) ]]; then
        threads="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "Process ID: $pid, Supervised Threads: $threads"
    fi
done <<< "$processes"
```

Comment: This results in "Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedProcesses" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1" doesn't exist" on my machine.