# rtkit daemon: setting logging for systemd service

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald, rtkit-daemon

My journal is littered with instances of

```
 rtkit-daemon[1407]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users1
```

I see this excellent post from @MC68020

[Stop rtkit-daemon from spamming logs with "Supervising X threads of Y processes of Z users"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684379/stop-rtkit-daemon-from-spamming-logs-with-supervising-x-threads-of-y-processes)

In which there is mention of a `rtkit-daemon.service.d` directory into which I can put a `log.conf` to set the logging priority of that service.

I dont' see that directory in my `Linux 6.2.11-arch1-1`

Comment: That directory won't exist until you create it. Search for "drop-in" in the [`systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) man page.

Comment: @larsks Nice! Great man page too.

Answer (score 1):

From @larks comment to this post and from the @MC68020 answer in [Stop rtkit-daemon from spamming logs with "Supervising X threads of Y processes of Z users"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684379/stop-rtkit-daemon-from-spamming-logs-with-supervising-x-threads-of-y-processes)

If `/usr/lib/systemd/system/rtkit-daemon.service.d`  does not exist, create it.

In that directory create a *.conf file, eg `log.conf` with the following content

```
 [Service]
 LogLevelMax=3
```

Where '3' is my choice from the following list

```
0 or emergency, (highest priority messages)
1 or alert,
2 or critical,
3 or error,
4 or warning,
5 or notice,
6 or info
7 or debuginfo (lowest priority messages)
```

Note that the default value for unspecified logging priority is `7` which will result in, for most users, an overly-informative service.